# Why is $e: [0,1) \to S^1$, $e(x)=e^{2 \pi i x}$ an open map?

Tags: general-topology

Where $[0,1]$ and $S^1$ have their respective standard topologies. I can’t come up with a nice argument why the stated function $e$ should be open. This comes from an ‘exercise to the reader’ where we specifically have to show that $e \circ q$ is open where $q : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R / \equiv$ the quotient map, where $x\equiv y$ if $x-y\in \mathbb Z$ and $e: \mathbb R/\equiv \to S^1$ with $x \mapsto e^{2 \pi i x}$. (I think) I’ve shown $q$ open and $[0,1)$ is a representation of $\mathbb R/\equiv$ so thus the question.

Comment: $e$ is not open. $[0,1/2)$ is an open subset of $[0,1)$ but its image by $e$ is not open in $S^1.$

Comment: Your question is unclear. $e\circ q$ does not exist since $q$ takes its values in $\Bbb R/\equiv$ and the domain of $e$ is $[0,1).$ And I don't know what "$[0,1)$ is a *representation* of $\Bbb R/≡$" means. Can you please reproduce *in your post* the *exact* statement of your exercise?

Comment: "$[0,1)$ is a representation of $\mathbb{R}/\equiv$" I don't know what that means. Regardless your first $e$ is not open, while the second one is.

Comment: Oh thank you @freakish I didn't notice there was a second $e.$ So Ali Alex I think you should change your title and stick to that second (more reasonable) $e.$

Comment: You seem to be confusing a true fact with a false fact. The true fact is that $[0,1)$ is a *set theoretic* representation of $\mathbb R / \equiv$, in the sense that every equivalence class of $\equiv$ contains a unique element of $[0,1)$. The false fact is that the function $[0,1) \to \mathbb R / \equiv$, which assigns to each $x \in [0,1)$ its equivalence class, is a homeomorphism with respect to the quotient topology on its codomain $\mathbb R  \equiv$. Although that map is certainly a continuous bijection, it is *not* an open map.

Comment: Thank you all! This was admittedly not a great question. @LeeMosher indeed I mistakenly assumed since e seemed open on $\mathbb R / \equiv$ it would also be on $[0,1)$ but I didn’t actually check… thank you for the details though.

Comment: Your new edit invalidates the accepted answer. That is an improper use of this site: now anyone who reads this post will be completely confused. Your edit should be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initially wanted to prove that $e:{\Bbb R/\equiv}\to S^1,\;x\bmod1\mapsto e^{2\pi ix}$ is open.

By definition of the quotient topology, this is equivalent to $e\circ q$ being open.

But $e\circ q:\Bbb R\to S^1,\;x\mapsto e^{2\pi ix}$ is even better: it is a local homeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give a hint or the idea behind that $e \circ q$ is a local homeomorphism?

Comment: I’ll mark this as answered because the comments and this answer are satisfactory to what I was looking for.

Comment: The restrictions of $e\circ q,$ from $(a,a+1)$ to $S^1\setminus\{e^{2\pi ia}\},$ are homeomorphisms.